# ¿Alguien sabe como hace Quasar.js para usar su diálogo de esta forma this.$q.dialgo.confirm()?

Tags: vue3, vuetify, quasar

Tengo un proyecto personal y estoy usando vuetify 3 y quiero crear un componente para confirmar acciones pero quiero usarlo como lo hace Quasar.js es decir como this.$q.dialgo.confirm() e investigado pero no he hallado la solución